# How to get selected value from dropdown list after submitting form in php

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to remain my drop down value which I select for submitting after posting the form. My form posts to the same page.

```
$query = "SELECT countryName,countryCode FROM   tcf_countries";                                                
$result = mysql_query ($query); 
echo "Country: <select name='country' value=''>"; 
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $r['countryCode'];
    $cname = $r['countryName'];
    echo "<option value=".$id.">".$cname."</option>";
}
echo "</select>"; ?>
```

Comment: Do not use mysql_* functions. Use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: As long as these antique "tutorials" stay on the web, they will use mysql forever until they delete it out of php.

Comment: Select hasn't the value attribute http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/select

Comment: Value is an attribute of option tag, not for the select tag

Answer (score 1):

Remove your current `echo` inside the loop and replace it with the following:

```
   if($_POST["country"]==$id)
     echo "<option value='".$id."' selected='selected'>".$cname."</option>";
   else
     echo "<option value='".$id."' >".$cname."</option>";
```

This will check if the current `option` being displayed is the one that was submitted and it will select it in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are looking for correctly you need to use the `$_POST` value of your select to set the selected item...

```
$query = "SELECT countryName,countryCode FROM   tcf_countries";
$result = mysql_query ($query); 
$country = '';
echo "Country: <select name='country'>"; 
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id = $r['countryCode'];
        $cname = $r['countryName'];
        echo "<option value=".$id;
        echo ($_POST["country"]==$id) ? ' selected="SELECTED"' : '';
        echo ">".$cname."</option>";
    }
echo "</select>"; ?>
```

Setting `selected="SELECTED"` for the `$id` that matches `$_POST['country']` will make it the selected item in your dropdown.

And, get rid of mysql* functions and use mysqli* functions instead...